# Cannot parse "2018 6 31 18 27 ": Value 31 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,30]

Tags: java, kotlin

Как бороться с такой ошибкой? При выборе 31 числа на месяц назад или вперёд.
Я ставлю на диалоге даты 31 октября, а ошибка на сентябрь идёт. На месяц назад.

`Cannot parse "2018 9 31 14 38": Value 31 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,30]`

```
val dateTime = DateTime.parse("$mYear-$mMonth-$mDay $hourOfDay:$minute", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

Comment: В июне 30 дней.

Comment: @Anamnian обновил запись. Я ставлю на диалоге даты 31 октября, а ошибка на сентябрь идёт.

Comment: В сентябре тоже 30 дней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val dateTime = DateTime.parse("$mYear-${mMonth+1}-$mDay $hourOfDay:$minute", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```